# How to convert JSON string having multiple rows to single row using javascript function

Tags: javascript, json

I have an output of REST API in following JSON format:
I need to convert the format to flat format so it can be passed as input to another API call.

```
{
  "result": {
    "data": [
      {
        "data": 2.824315071105957,
        "dateTime": "2019-09-10T11:32:05.220Z",
        "device": { "id": "b3" },
        "diagnostic": { "id": "DiagnosticAccelerationForwardBrakingId" },
        "controller": "ControllerNoneId",
        "version": "00000000000363b0",
        "id": "a5UyPzhknSC-N2wtLBph3BA"
      },
      {
        "data": 0,
        "dateTime": "2019-09-10T11:32:05.220Z",
        "device": { "id": "b3" },
        "diagnostic": { "id": "DiagnosticAccelerationSideToSideId" },
        "controller": "ControllerNoneId",
        "version": "00000000000363b1",
        "id": "a5UyPzhknSC-N2wtLBph3BQ"
      },
      // ... 1000's of rows like this
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to convert it in below format using a java-script

Desired format:

```
{"result":{ "data":[{"id":"b3","dateTime":"2019-09- 10T11:32:05.220Z","DiagnosticAccelerationSideToSideId":0,"DiagnosticAccelerationForwardBrakingId ":2.824315071105957},...
```

The rows needs to be merged with primary key as combination of ID and dateTime attributes. Please note the diagnostic id value becomes key for the required format and data value is the value of the key.

Is there any way to convert this JSON to above flat format.

Need to convert JSON having many rows for single data entry to single row format. Need one java-script function that can accept a string of rows format and convert or merge it and return the string in desired format

```
function String mergeRows(String flatDataJSONString) {
...
}
```

Comment: Why do I feel that some places in above snippet should be having square braces instead of curly braces?

Comment: You are right the correct structure is as below, I will update in above sample as well: {
"result":{
"data":[
{
"data": 1,
"dateTime": "2019-09-10T10:46:47.063Z",
"device":{"id": "b3"},
"diagnostic":{"id": "DiagnosticIgnitionId"},
"controller": "ControllerNoneId",
"version": "000000000003627c",
"id": "aPaDxqeiQ-yIozH_uM8CqAA"
},

Comment: is it me or do the first and second look the same?

Comment: Yes Ayyash, its almost same except the data element is array and needs a square braces not curly braces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the items are ordered (meaning i and i+1 are merged) than iterate with jumps of i += 2;

If its not ordered or the amount of items to be merged can be > 2 you use an object with unique key composed of the id and date, and override its data whenever a record match this key:

```
function merger (jsonStr) {
    // convert str to obj
    const jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
    const dataObj = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < jsonObj.result.length; i++) {
        const item = jsonObj.result[i];
        // use unique key to merge by
        const itemUniqueKey = item.device.id + item.dateTime;
        // take last value or create empty object if not exists
        const existingItem = dataObj[itemUniqueKey] || {};
        // add some logic to merge item with existingItem as you need
        ...
        // set the result back to dataObj to be used on next merges
        dataObj[itemUniqueKey] = [merge result of item and existing item];
    }
    // take dataObj values, you don't need the keys any more
    const dataArr = Object.values(dataObj);
    const finalResult = {
        result: {
            data: dataArr
        }
    }
    // convert back to json
    return JSON.stringify(finalResult);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is useful, Can you please explain the merge logic as well, I need to merge and make values as keys

Comment: Thanks @Lior, I am able to make it work by following logic:
 if(dataObj[itemUniqueKey]==null) {
   dataObj[itemUniqueKey]='"id":"' + item.device.id + '","dateTime":"' + item.dateTime+ '","' + item.diagnostic.id + '":' + item.data;
  } else {
   dataObj[itemUniqueKey]=dataObj[itemUniqueKey] + ',"' + item.diagnostic.id + '":' + item.data;
  }
This resolved the question.

Comment: Great, glad it helps

Answer (score -1):

As stated in the comment you want first to have a clean json definition in order to stringify it. Please get to the following definition of your JSON first:

```
const json = {
        "result": [
            {
                "data": 2.824315071105957,
                "dateTime": "2019-09-10T11:32:05.220Z",
                "device": { "id": "b3" },
                "diagnostic": { "id": "DiagnosticAccelerationForwardBrakingId" },
                "controller": "ControllerNoneId",
                "version": "00000000000363b0",
                "id": "a5UyPzhknSC-N2wtLBph3BA"
            },
            {
                "data": 0,
                "dateTime": "2019-09-10T11:32:05.220Z",
                "device": { "id": "b3" },
                "diagnostic": { "id": "DiagnosticAccelerationSideToSideId" },
                "controller": "ControllerNoneId",
                "version": "00000000000363b1",
                "id": "a5UyPzhknSC-N2wtLBph3BQ"
            }]
    };
```

and then you will be able to perform like hereafter :

```
JSON.stringify(json)
```

Hope this helps !